# Trapz gives negative result: why?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically integrate a [Generalized Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution). I expect the area under it to be 1. What I get is -1. Why is it like this?

```
mu=0;
alpha=0.5;
beta=2;

x=-2:0.01:2;
densityGG = beta/(2*alpha*gamma(1/beta)) * exp(-power(abs(x-mu)/alpha,beta));

plot(x,densityGG);
trapz(densityGG,x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is actually

```
trapz(X, Y)
```

So try

```
trapz(x, densityGG)
```

and it should sort things out.

Comment: Maybe its really time for me to take a break... thanks a lot for the tip and sorry for the dummy question. :P

Answer (score 2):

read the help file of [Trapz](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trapz.html)... it's all there

you need to write:
    trapz(x,densityGG)